# Как реализовать i18n и l10n в Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, локализация

Если вкратце, то я уже реализовал локализацию и интернационализацию в Spring Boot традиционным способом описанным тут: 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization
Говоря проще, все файлы локализации хранятся в messages.properties и соответственно, при необходимости достаются оттуда.
Но есть некий динамический контент, хранимый в БД, который также требует локализации. Не редактировать же каждый раз файл messages.properties.
Нашел следующую реализацию, когда для локализации создается отдельный Entity, где он хранится в БД в паре ключ - значение.
https://medium.com/i18n-and-l10n-resources-for-developers/database-stored-messages-for-i18n-in-spring-boot-11dc2ee5c1f7
Как быть с тем случаем, когда тексты локализации планируется хранить в соответствующим таблицах Entity классов?
Например, есть Entity - Article. Соответственно, будут колонки title_ru content_ru title_en content_en и соответственно, при обращении доставать нужные переводы... Что является правилом хорошего тона в данном случае?
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А если понадобиться поддерживать ещё один язык, будете делать alter таблице? А если языков будет 50, то будет 100 колонок? Лучше добавить одну колонку для хранения языка и хранить несколько строк для разных языков.

Comment: Ой, здравствуйте! Я вас еще с Тостера помню))) В принципе, я согласен с вами с этой идеей... Пожалуй, так и реализую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал решение найденное здесь - 
https://medium.com/i18n-and-l10n-resources-for-developers/database-stored-messages-for-i18n-in-spring-boot-11dc2ee5c1f7